# PHP - https stream through http proxy

Tags: php, curl, https, proxy, stream

I'm trying to get the content of a stream over HTTPS, but I have to go over an HTTP proxy.
I'd like not to use cURL but rather use **fopen** with a **context** argument.

The thing is, I can't make it work over HTTPS (HTTP is working fine though).

This **DOES NOT** work :

```
$stream = stream_context_create(Array("http" => Array("method"  => "GET",
                                                      "timeout" => 20,
                                                      "proxy"   => "tcp://my-proxy:3128",
                                                      'request_fulluri' => True 
                                )));
echo file_get_contents('https://my-stream', false, $context);
```

This **DOES** work (cURL) :

```
$url = 'https://my-stream';
$proxy = 'my-proxy:3128';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
$curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $curl_scraped_page;
```

Does somebody know what is wrong with the first piece of code ? if it works with cURL there has to be a way to make it work with a context.
I tried to change the context options to a bunch of different values woth no luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Thanks.

Comment: From what I recall, the key in the array passed to `stream_context_create` is the protocol that will be used.  Try switching the key from http to https.

Comment: Thanks, but I tried, with no luck. I read some code snippets where people make https request without changing the key to 'https'. The only difference here is that i'm using a proxy :/

Comment: Changing the key to `https` is incorrect! `https://` calls will use the `http` context and then the underlying `ssl` transport context.

Answer (score 7):

You did not specifiy the exact error message, try adding `ignore_errors => true`. But if you are getting a `400 Bad Request` from Apache, the problem you are probably hitting, is a Server Name Indication & host header mismatch. There is also a PHP bug related to this: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=63519

Try the following fix until this bug is resolved:

```
$stream = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'timeout' => 20,
        'proxy' => 'tcp://my-proxy:3128',
        'request_fulluri' => true 
    ),
    'ssl' => array(
        'SNI_enabled' => false // Disable SNI for https over http proxies
    )
));
echo file_get_contents('https://my-stream', false, $context);
```